How can I display an error message from a command in a .bat file?
I have a Windows batch file containing the command rmdir dirname. rmdir can produce a number of different error messages if it fails.
The command
mshta "javascript:var sh=new ActiveXObject( 'WScript.Shell' ); sh.Popup( "Message', 10,    'Title!', 64 );close()"

displays a fixed message. How can I use mshta (or other functionality) to display the failure message from a preceding command?
In response to to Yisroel Tech answer
When I run
C:\Windows\System32>Set CamTrapProDir = %APPDATA%\CamTrapPro
C:\Windows\System32>for /f "delims=" %%a in ('rmdir "%CamTrapProDir%" 2^>^&1') do set "errmsg=%%a"

I get
%%a was unexpected at this time.

Response to dave_thomson
The .bat file containing the following worked OK:
for /f  %%a in ('rmdir "%APPDATA%\CamTrapPro" 2^>^&1') do set "%%errmsg=%%a"
if defined errmsg (
    mshta "javascript:var sh=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'); sh.Popup('%errmsg%', 8, 'Error', 16);close()"
) else (
    mshta "javascript:var sh=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'); sh.Popup('CamTrap Pro data removed successfully.', 16, 'Success', 64);close()"
)


That specific for command only works in a batch file, which is what your Q asked for. To work interactively, as you apparently tried, you must change %%a to %a i.e. undouble the % for the variable. This is effectively explained in the builtin help ( for /? ) halfway down the first screen.

You can capture the error into a variable, and then use the variable in the mshta popup.
Something like this:
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('rmdir "%dirname%" 2^>^&1') do set "errmsg=%%a"

if defined errmsg (
    mshta "javascript:var sh=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'); sh.Popup('%errmsg%', 10, 'Error', 16);close()"
) else (
    mshta "javascript:var sh=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'); sh.Popup('Directory removed successfully.', 10, 'Success', 64);close()"
)


See edited question
